# Debugger's watch window shows the variables values as zero but they are not

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, mfc

I have structure statically allocated. It has couple of arrays. When I see the values of these arrays they are displayed but all values are zero (0). When I werite this array to file, the values are correct however if I watch the values at the same time in debugger the values show up as zero. I used TRACE to print the values on output window and that is also correct.

So the program is doing all computation correctly but debugger shows the variables' values all zero. I am using VS2010 and C++. Is there a way to fix it?

p.s I have tried other solutions listed around like typing array_name,number in debugger but that doesn't work for me either.

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem. Variables show correct values in watch both in main and if array is passed as an argument?

Comment: @C.Lang I suspect it can't be reproduced in a simple project. In my case the structure is part of application class (MFC) and there are a number of other structures there. This structure is also passed as pointer (don't ask y,not my code!) I did create a simple test array in the function and just copied that array into it and hoped this array will show the values correctly but even in new array it still doesn't.`WORD dbgSubPwr[COUNT] = {0};memcpy(dbgSubPwr, record->m_pwSubPwr, sizeof(WORD) * COUNT );` I suspect the stack has reached the limits perhaps that's why? but is it documented anywhere?

Comment: the joys of debugging. Never had your issue before, but then again I don't use MFC much.. (aka, I avoid it like the death plague). Stack size is limited, and if you was exceeding it you'd get a nasty error that your not reporting.

Comment: @johnathon It's more like the joy of working with microsoft products!